# "It is not necessarily be limited"

Tags: tense

I recently received a mail, and ever since I have been whacking my head if the sentence is right. "Although, the requirement is Modeling (Using a software) **it is not necessarily be limited to it**." The part of the sentence in Bold is what has me confused. Can anyone clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

//"Although, the requirement is Modeling (Using a software) it (the requirement)is not necessarily be limited to it."//

If 'be' before limited is knocked off, it will be a correct sentence. "...it is not necessarily be limited to it" - this part has a repetition of BE form.